# Fail to run MySQL in Mac OSX 10.5.8

Tags: macos, mac, installation, mysql

my mac is a powerPC.  and I have tried both 64 bit and 32 bit version.

Both return me "**bad CPU type in executable**"   when I try to do this /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

I followed all the steps as specified in the mysql official website.

Answer (score 0):

All the versions on http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ for Mac OSX are for x86 that is Intel computers.